# Solr 7.3.0 copyField doesn't work as expected

Tags: solr

With `Solr 7,` `defaultSearchField` has been deprecated(?) so I did this in
`solrconfig.xml`.

```
<requestHandler name='/select' class='solr.SearchHandler' default='true' df='fullText' q.op='OR' />
```

I'm not sure if I'm correct as this is my first time working with `XMLs` and `Solr`.

This is part of my schema.

```
        <fields>
        <field name='id' type='long' required='true' />
        <field name='searchdata' type='string' required='true' />
        <field name='searchtype' type='long' required='true' />
        <dynamicField name='*_string' type='string' multiValued='true' indexed='true' stored='true' />
        <copyField source='*' dest='fullText' />
        <field name='fullText' type='string' multiValued='true' indexed='true' />
    </fields>
```

I am working on a search bar kind of page and require a field that contains all the text of the data hence the naming `"fullText"`.

Answer (score 1):

That not how you set static request values in Solr. Use [the proper syntax and it should work as you expect](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/requesthandlers-and-searchcomponents-in-solrconfig.html#RequestHandlersandSearchComponentsinSolrConfig-SearchHandlers):

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="df">fullText</str>
    <str name="q.op">OR</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Be aware that a `string` field will only give you exact matches.